# How can i display an image to ImageButton asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

This Updates the database by inserting the image file to avatar column. The uploading to database works but it wont display in image button.

```
protected void imgProfile_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    try
    {
        FileUpload img = (FileUpload)ofd;
        Byte[] imgByte = null;
        if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null)
        {
            //To create a PostedFile
            HttpPostedFile File = ofd.PostedFile;
            //Create byte Array with file len
            imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
            //force the control to load data in array
            File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
        }
        // Insert the employee name and image into db
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SE255_AFloresConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
        connection = new SqlConnection(conn);

        connection.Open();
        string sql = "UPDATE Users SET Avatar = ('" + imgByte + "') OUTPUT INSERTED.User_ID WHERE Username = ('" + Session["UserName"].ToString() + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        userid.Text = "<script>alert('" + String.Format("Employee ID is" +" "+ id) + "')</script>";
        userid.Visible = false;

        //display
        imgProfile.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + id;
    }
    catch
    {
        //lblResult.Text = "There was an error";
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
```

This Part is where i am stuck on it wont display it on image button please help

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    Int32 empno;
    if (context.Request.QueryString["User_ID"] != null)
        empno = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["User_ID"]);
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(empno);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

    while (byteSeq > 0)
    {
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
        byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
    }       
}
public Stream ShowEmpImage(int empno)
{

    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SE255_AFloresConnctionString2"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    string sql = "SELECT Avatar FROM Users WHERE User_ID = @ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", empno);
    connection.Open();
    object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    try
    {
        return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

This is the .aspx file

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function clk() {
        var ofd = document.getElementById('<%=ofd.ClientID%>');
        ofd.click();
    }
```

```
<asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="userid" runat="server"></asp:Label>


<div style="width:100%;">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgProfile" CssClass="img-circle img img-rounded" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" OnClientClick="clk();" OnClick="imgProfile_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
    <div style="display:none">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="ofd" runat="server" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: imgProfile.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + id;

What this line will do? If it will call a async handler class which will return the image as a bit stream, it will not work. This is not a right path to assign as an imageUrl.

Comment: can you tell me what would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
imgProfile.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

Try the above lines in a method that fetches the image bytes from the database. To do this you don't even need ashx handler. Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Do i replace `bytes` to `imgByte` like i have above? do i need handler? this is the first time i do this so i really don't understand much

Comment: string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgByte , 0, imgByte.Length);
imgProfile.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

       
use the above two lines to replace your line -      imgProfile.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + id;      
   
 This way we take the bytes of the file from the fileupload control, save it to the database and the same time we convert that byte to base64String format and assign to ImageUrl property with the tag mentioning it is a base64 bytes content.

Answer (score 0):

To make it better way, add this method in your class and call it to take the bytes from the database after we save it to database.

```
public string GetImageAsByte64String(int empno)
{

string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SE255_AFloresConnctionString2"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
string sql = "SELECT Avatar FROM Users WHERE User_ID = @ID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", empno);
connection.Open();
object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
try
{
    byte[] imgByte = (byte[])img;
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgByte , 0, imgByte.Length);
    return  ("data:image/png;base64," + base64String);

}
catch
{
    return null;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
}
```

Later call this method as below to assign to your ImageUrl property of the imageButton.

```
//display
imgProfile.ImageUrl = GetImageAsByte64String(id);
```

Comment: i decided to do it different way where it gets file name and puts it in database as a path instead of a byte `ofd.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + name));` because i know nothing about http handler and its too much work. The problem im having is that the `HasFile` returns false when an image is selected do you have any ideas?

Comment: Using only the path of the image to keep record in database is the easiest way, although its not the best. May I know what did failed in the above code? So that I can look into fix it if you still like to proceed.

Comment: still doesn't display the image